# Where does a compiled function get its globals()?

Tags: python, disassembly

I've discovered that if I write something like:

```
code = f"lambda a, b: add(a, b)"
my_globals = globals().copy()
my_globals['add'] = operator.__add__
result = eval(code, my_globals, {})
```

Then `result(3, 5)` has the value 8, just like I want.

When I look at the disassembly of `result`, I see:

```
 0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (add)
 2 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
 4 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
 6 CALL_FUNCTION            2
 8 RETURN_VALUE
```

How does `LOAD_GLOBAL` convert `add` into `operator.__add__`?  It clearly must save a reference to `my_globals` somewhere inside itself or its `__code__` object..  But I've been unable to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference you seek is the `__globals__` attribute of the function object:

```
>>> result.__globals__
{'__name__': '__main__',
 # Many lines omitted
 'operator': <module 'operator' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/operator.py'>,
 'code': 'lambda a, b: add(a, b)',
 'add': <function _operator.add(a, b, /)>}
```

This attribute is documented in the [Python Data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), under special attributes for user-defined functions:

> `__globals__`: 
> A reference to the dictionary that holds the function’s global variables — the global namespace of the module in which the function was defined. 
> Read-only

As you found, the code object itself (`__code__`) does not contain a reference to the applicable globals dictionary. This is explicitly mentioned in the data model docs under "code objects":

> Code objects represent byte-compiled executable Python code, or bytecode. The difference between a code object and a function object is that **the function object contains an explicit reference to the function’s globals** (the module in which it was defined), while a code object contains no context; also the default argument values are stored in the function object, not in the code object (because they represent values calculated at run-time). Unlike function objects, code objects are immutable and contain no references (directly or indirectly) to mutable objects.

Comment: Thank you.  I looked at `__globals__`, but the "many lines omitted" caused me to miss it.  I just saw one big copyright notice and didn't see them hiding off the end of it.

Answer (score 3):

`globals` (and hence your `my_globals`) is just a dictionary.  It happens to be the default dictionary search for names at a global level, which LOAD_GLOBAL knows how to find.  In your example, that master dictionary is your `my_globals`.  You won't find a reference to it; it's internal to the interpreter.